# I want to implement ISupportLastWriteTime in sync framework 2.1

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Implementing ISupportLastWriteTime in sync framework 2.1 but there is not even a single piece of code on the internet.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744781(v=vs.85).aspx
```

I want to implement the Last writer wins in the sync framework 2.1

and i cannot add a new column in the existing tables.

I had created **RelationalSyncProvider**

```
 private void LocalProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {
    //    ISupportLastWriteTime t = sender;

    //    t.GetChangeUnitChangeTime(

        if (dbInfo.SynchronizeDirection == eSyncDirection.Download)
        {
        }
```

Here how can i implement ISupportLastWriteTime

Please help......

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, the RelationalSyncProvider lacks the the functionality to do Last Writer Wins type of resolution.

the easiest way to do this is to add a Last Update DateTime on your tables and when it fires a conflict, compare them and specify which row wins.

Comment: i did this using Tracking tables timestamp using sqlcommands but i want to implement the  ISupportLastWriteTime  there must be some way, if microsoft has created this interface it must be of some use some how isnt it.